# Find locus of points in first octant giving minimum volume

Tags: geometry, locus

The problem: Let $\Bbb R_+^3$ be the first coordinate octant in $R^3$. Then for each fixed $\alpha > 0$ describe the geometric location of points $A \in \Bbb R_+^3$, which satisfy the following condition: the smallest volume of the part of the octant cut off by an arbitrary plane drawn through $A$ is equal to $\alpha$.

As I understand I need to find points. Part of octant will be a pyramid. Its volume must be equal to $\alpha$. We can use the formula:
$$V = \frac{1}{3}S \cdot h$$
So,
$$\alpha = \frac{1}{3}S \cdot h$$
As there must be at least $3$ points to draw the plane, then they will be at $(x;0;0)$, $(0;y;0)$, $(0;0;z)$. So I can rewrite our formula that way:
$$\alpha = \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot x \cdot y \cdot z = \frac{xyz}{6} $$
But it's not the full answer. I don't know what to do next. Tell me if I'm wrong somewhere and what should I do?

Comment: Write down the condition for $A$ to lie on the plane defined by your three points, minimize the volume subject to this constraint before setting the volume equal to $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P=(x,y,z)$ be any point in the first octant. Any plane cutting the positive semi-axes at $(a,0,0)$, $(0,b,0)$, $(0,0,c)$ passes through $P$ if:
$$
{x\over a}+{y\over b}+{z\over c}=1
$$
and the volume cut off by such a plane is:
$$
V={1\over 6}abc.
$$
By AM-GM inequality we have:
$$
\root{3}\of{1\over V}=\root{3}\of{6\over abc}=
\root{3}\of{6\over xyz}\root{3}\of{xyz\over abc}\le
\root{3}\of{6\over xyz}{1\over3}\left({x\over a}+{y\over b}+{z\over c}\right)=
{1\over3}\root{3}\of{6\over xyz}$$
with equality reached when
$$
{x\over a}={y\over b}={z\over c}={1\over3}.
$$
Hence the minimum volume is
$$
\alpha=27{xyz\over 6}
$$
and this is the equation of the requested locus.